# Smoothing out multi-colored line segments

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am producing a graph

[image]

using [python matplotlib with a line color gradient and colorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36074455/python-matplotlib-with-a-line-color-gradient-and-colorbar)

Everything seems fine but in higher resolution one can notice the breaks between line segments as in next image:

[image]

Is there any way to smooth out this graph? I figured one could perhaps artificially increase the number of data points in the vulnerable areas of joints but I was not able to implement it successfully.

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47856091/4124317) would show a possible way of "smoothing" by increasing the number of points drawn. It may get you started. For this question to be answered, following the above comment would still make sense.