# HSV colormap in matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, hsv

I am trying to reproduce a graph that shows the
[hue distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmLUW.png) of an image using an HSV colormap.

I have the information related to the hue channel represented as a dict, aggregated on multiple samples:

```json
hue = {
    0 : hue_0,
    1 : hue_1,
    ...
  255 : hue_255
}
```

I have tried to use matplotlib's `colorline` example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36074455/python-matplotlib-with-a-line-color-gradient-and-colorbar) in the following way:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = list(hue.keys())
y = list(hue.values())

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
lc = colorline(x, y, cmap='hsv')
plt.colorbar(lc)
plt.xlim(0, 255)
plt.ylim(0, max(y))
plt.show()
```

but it produced [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOLPr.png).

I have figured how to plot the hue dict as a line:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lists = sorted(hue.items())

x, y = zip(*lists)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

But I cannot figure out how to add an HSV colormap to the plot.

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation on matplotlib about colorline. Is it a custom function or part of a different library?

Comment: Maybe it is related to matplotlib's [multicolored line example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html)?

Comment: The colorline example is from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36074455/python-matplotlib-with-a-line-color-gradient-and-colorbar

Comment: Wouldn't calling `colorline(x, y, cmap='hsv')` on the sorted `x` and `y` do the job?